# How do I download current kernel source

Tags: kernel, source

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running kernel 4.10.0-27-generic.

`uname -a` shows

```
Linux my-pc 4.10.0-27-generic #30~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 16:07:46 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I download the kernel source

```
apt-get source linux-image-4.10.0-27-generic
```

I get the message

```
Picking 'linux-hwe' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.10.0-27-generic'
```

When I check the kernel version of the downloaded source

```
make kernelversion
```

The version is reported as

```
4.10.17
```

How do I download the actual source for the actual kernel I am currently running ?

When compiling the kernel, how do I specify the target architecture ? (amd64 for me).

Comment: Might have figured this out. Do I simply download the latest linux-hwe source and answer "no" to all new features at configure time ? Does that acheive the same result ?

Comment: The target architecture will by default the same as it is already in your system.

Answer (score 3):

You downloaded the source correctly.

`make kernelversion` will never give you the correct Ubuntu kernel version. It outputs the mainline version.

It may be done by some command, but the easiest way is to look into `debian.master/changelog`.

A better way is to get sources from `git`. Run

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git
cd ubuntu-xenial
git checkout 6cac304f7f239ac
```

and you will get your `4.10.0-27` kernel source.

Comment: The latest entry in that change log is for 4.10.0-26.30. I am running 4.10.0-27-generic. Does that sound right ?

Comment: It looks almost right. I think that if you download the source again, it will be 4.10.0-27.

Comment: Just did an apt-get update then performed the download again. Same version is shown in the change log.

Comment: This looks wierd. Where did you get the 4.10.0-27? Maybe proposed repo is enabled... The current hwe kernel is 4.10.0-26.

Comment: Also try `sudo apt install  linux-source-4.10.0`. That has 4.10.0-27 version. You can also clone the source from git and checkout whatever version you like.

Comment: And also make sure you build a Debian way, not by `make` command.

Comment: I do build the debian way, yes.  Had a look at my sources.list file and I do have a xenial-backports entry, but no proposed entry.

Comment: This is some repo inconsistency. I prefer to get sources from `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git`. You can checkout what you want and not depend on the repos.

Comment: Is there a list anywhere of the commit checksums for each kernel revision? Or is there a git command that will list the branches/tags. I'm not quite sure how you got from wanting version `4.10.0-27` to using `git checkout 6cac304f7f239ac`

Comment: See http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/log/?qt=range&q=6cac304f7f239ac

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Also - makes sure you enable the source urls in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: This describes the HWE kernel dev environment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: That won't get any sources any more. `unsigned` is needed. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171491/why-is-apt-source-picking-linux-signed-hwe-instead-of-a-real-kernel